# Allow some SQL in public API?

Tags: sql, api

I'm exposing a more or less public API that allows the user to query datasets from a database. Since the user will need to filter out specific datasets I'm tempted to accept the WHERE-part of the SELECT statement as an API parameter. Thus the user could perform queries as complex as she'd like without worrying about a cluttered API interface.

I'm aware of the fact that I would have to catch SQL-injection attempts.

Do you think that this would circumvent the purpose of an API wrapping a database too much or would you consider this a sane approach?

Comment: `WHERE 1=1; DROP bobby_tables;`

Comment: @Dems +1 for an XKCD Reference

Comment: Even if you force me to only be able to modify the where clause, I can just DoS you with table scans. :|

Comment: XKCD: "Exploits of a Mom": http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Dems I fail to understand why Db Connectivity API (or RDBMS) doesn't throw an error when running executeQuery("select 1 from customer; drop table customer;") Better example is UNION injection.

Comment: @Strange Impose session resource limit?

Comment: @TegiriNenashi: Only if he wants to create unique SQL accounts per API user (a bit of annoying work), otherwise I can just lock everyone out of the API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I'd recommend against letting them embed actual sql in their requests

You can allow them to submit `where` conditions in their request pretty easily:

```
<where>
    <condition "field"="name" "operator"="equal" "value"="Fred"/>
</where>
```

or something similar.

The value of doing this is muli-fold:

1. You parse each condition and make sure they're correct before running them
2. You can create 'fake' fields, such as "full_name" that may not exist.
3. You can limit the columns they can put conditions on
4. You can isolate the users from actual changes in your underlying database.

I think the last point is actually most important. The day will come when you'll need to make changes to the underlying schema of the database. Eventually, it will happen. At that point you'll appreciate having some 'translation' layer between what the users send in and the queries. It will allow you to isolate the users from actual changes in the underlying database.

The API should present an 'abstracted' version of the actual tables themselves that meet the users needs and isolate them from changes to the actual underlying database.

Comment: +1 - This would be the equivalent (and should probably actually use, anyways) of using a view in the database layer itself.

Comment: Great answer. You caught the reasons for my vague doubts towards this approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend limitting your users account by modifying the permissions to only allow the user to `SELECT` from tables.  Don't allow updating, inserting, or deleting recordsets.  Lock down the user as much as possibile, possibly at a table level.

Answer (score 0):

If the `WHERE` clause is limited to only a few columns and the comparator is limited to `>, =` or `<` then perhaps you could just have the user pass in some extra parameters to represent columns and comparators. You then build the `WHERE` safely on your server side.

If this is too messy then by all means let them pass a full `WHERE` clause - it's not too hard to sanitise and if you combine that with running the query under a locked-down account (`SELECT` only), then any potential damage is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not want to allow users to be able to pass in SQL directly to my database, the risks are too great.

If you fail to catch all injection attempts you risk either data theft, someone just destroying your database or hijacking it for some other use that you really dont want.