# Opening SQL read-access up to the public without allowing abuse

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm considering allowing the public to make read-only SQL queries on a public dataset. Previously, I've mentioned this on the Stack Exchange Chat PHP page and was immediately met with a massive `no...no...nooooooooooo!!!!!!`-style response.

People seem to think it is far too dangerous. One person likened it to putting the safety lock on a gun and hoping no-one gets shot. No-one really went into more details but someone mentioned system calls. **My question is what risks am I running by doing this and what measures can be taken to counteract that risk (like timeouts to stop infinite loops)?**

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983753/allow-some-sql-in-public-api) question covers the topic a bit, but is about partial user-controlable querys, not total control. It also doesn't answer my question.

EDIT: To clarify, what specific steps can I take to stop resource hogging (infinite loops, etc). There is nothing currently in place to control queries. Queries run through a PHP page.

Comment: Goodle `SQL Injection`.

Comment: See http://xkcd.com/327/ for an example.

Comment: It goes without saying that everyone except a single dedicated admin account (with very strong password) would only have `select` access, and on just the tables needed, revoking everything else. You should use a "burner" database, keeping a backup on a different machine. If the data is "static", have an overnight reload (actually, drop tables and recreate) of the database from a backup. Don't run anything else on that server, and don't have it inside your own network. Perhaps you could ask some of the sites like sqlfiddle.com what they do (though their use case is slightly different).

Comment: @PM77-1. Of course I know about SQL injection. I'm talking about allowing **read-only** access to SQL queries.

Comment: There is no way for us to know what risks **you or your server** will encounter without knowing what all is in the database, what else is on the server, what is in place to control queries, and possibly many other details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say go for it.

For all the people who said `no...no...nooooooooooo!!!!!!`, consider this:

StackOverflow (through Meta Stack Exchange) offers TO ANYONE free access to their posts. This access is done via an open sql format. Don't believe me? Try for yourself: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Want an example of a query I wrote? Here: [Tag usage over time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255313/tag-usage-over-time)

To mitigate the danger of exposing your data, consider this:

- don't expose a direct connection to your database through a sql client. Consider using a web page that accepts SQL queries and returns the result.
- parse the sql command for any suspicious commands. Hard, I know, but you could, for example, prevent the use of sql functions.
- remember that this has to run on a machine, so consider security and keep this machine isolated from the core.
- consider killing a query that is taking too long to finish.
- Comes without saying: don't keep any identifiable/user information in there.
- Consider refreshing the schema periodically.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a careful job of locking down your MySQL server's protections, and publishing only a username that permits reading the various tables, you should be able to allow some basic access and prevent naive attacks on your server (like `TRUNCATE TABLE mydata` and the like).

It's the more sophisticated attacks that are worrisome.

It's not hard to write long-running data-exploding queries that will be indistinguishable from a denial-of-service attack. Unconstrained self-joins are a simple example. It's also not hard, if your MySQL port is listening on a public IP address, for a clumsy or malicious user to fill up your connection table or cursor table and make your server inaccessible.

So, I suggest you go for it. But treat your publicly visible server as a sacrificial lamb. Set it up as some sort of clone of your master server (but without live links back to its master). Put it out there on the public net with the expectation that intertoobz wolves will attack and slaughter it. When they do, just restore it and carry on.  This is the way http://sqlfiddle.com/ works, and it works pretty well.

Another choice might be to hide your MySQL server behind a securely designed web service that serializes and controls access to it.

Comment: My SQL port will not be open, but what can I do to stop resource hogging?